# HTML Button Run Java

Tags: java

I have an HTML form that I want a user to fill out, and then send by pressing a button. Is there a way to have that button run a java program with all the HTML input as parameters? I looked into this a bit, and most people recommended servlets. Is there a way to do this without a servlet?

Edit: I'm not trying to use a servlet because of restrictions.

Comment: What requires java? Perhaps a js solution would be better

Comment: Are you meaning by using an applet?

Comment: Could you use CGI and have that execute a Java program? Also, do you want the Java program to run on the server or the client?

Comment: I need java to write to Excel. I would like the java program to run on the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a restriction against running a servlet you're pretty much out of luck in terms of using java. You could use a JSP, but that's just a servlet at the end of the day. You could use javascript to pop-up a mail-to with the form parameters entered as the body of the email but that would assume the user has a mail program configured. You could use some service like http://www.emailmeform.com/ (I have no idea if this one is good, I just googled it...).

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Java Web Start](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136112.html), might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the java **client-side** or **server-side**? The two posted answers are client-side answers. As for **server-side**, the tutorial [here](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Java-CGI-HOWTO-2.html) might help, depending on your server.